# Kivy fails to build

Tags: python, macos, kivy, zsh, macos-catalina

my Kivy build failed; I followed the instructions on [GitHub](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios).
My specs are:

```
macOS Catalina 10.15.5
XCode 11.5 (incl. CL Tools)
```

I have 2 suspicions why this might fail.

1. the python3 recipe lists version 3.8.2
2. Some somehow it is not downloading openssl as shown in the error message below

Command:

```
(venv) User-MBP ~ % toolchain build python3 kivy
```

Error:

```
...
[INFO    ] Download hostopenssl
[INFO    ] Downloading http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1f.tar.gz
[WARNING ] Download failed. Retrying in 1 second...
[WARNING ] Download failed. Retrying in 1 second...
[WARNING ] Download failed. Retrying in 1 second...
[WARNING ] Download failed. Retrying in 1 second...
[ERROR   ] Max download attempts reached: 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1756, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1965, in open_https
    return self._open_generic_http(self._https_connection, url, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1914, in _open_generic_http
    http_conn.request("GET", selector, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should give full access to the installation folder read & write

I advise you

1. create a installation folder example build.
   give full access to build folder (read & write)
   install all within that folder
2. % cd build
3. cd build% sudo -H toolchain build python3 kivy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5bAglvrUgQ

Comment: thanks, very strange I couldn't get it to work. I downgraded XCode and followed the steps- works now!

Comment: let me know if you need help, I can help you remotely